# Can't login with Selenium Python in Microsoft company account through ADFS. Any tips?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, adfs

How to inspect a ADFS ?!
Can´t get through via Selenium Python in my company account!!
I´ve seen people talk about it, but have never seen no one on youtube dealing with ADFS!!

My code.:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

service_obj = Service("C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service_obj)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://login.intranet.xx.com.br/")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#idToken1").send_keys("NAME")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "idToken3").send_keys("PASSWORD")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginButton_0"]').click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btn-action").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "menuAplicativos").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "6d59167f9bac0c5822dd4168a7c7b5a15a5f21e3930fa18c94a9837c3291ee15").click()
windowsOpened = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(windowsOpened[1])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//a[@title='E-mail'])[2]").click()
windowsOpened = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(windowsOpened[2])
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[onclick='goToOffice()']").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "i0116").send_keys("EMAIL")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#idSIButton9").click()
driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys("EMAIL")
driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys("PASSWORD")
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

[ADFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkAgy.png)

Comment: is this id `6d59167f9bac0c5822dd4168a7c7b5a15a5f21e3930fa18c94a9837c3291ee15` always the same?

Comment: Yes mate, it seems to repeat..just did it again now. id="6d59167f9bac0c5822dd4168a7c7b5a15a5f21e3930fa18c94a9837c3291ee15"

Comment: shouldn't it be `idToken1` and `idToken2` instead of `idToken3`

Comment: The whole code is fine, what i need is how to inspect de ADFS. Open the picture i´ve sent.

Comment: ah, thats the/an http authorization dialog

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a username and password to the url

`https://username:password@URL`

such as

`https://username:password@www.example.com/`

This is because the link you are trying to access required a http creds

[read more here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http-basic-authentication-url-with-in-password)